# eclipselink auto generated key : sql server last_insert_id' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jpa, eclipselink

I migrated my DB from mysql to sql server 2008 and now trying to configure my ORM, but getting this exception when trying to insert a new item into table. I have tested it 2 tables with and without identity column and also `GeneretionType.AUTO` and `GeneretionType.IDENTITY` in my entity but it doesnt work.

How can I insert `ID` field automatically with eclipselink to sql server 2008 ?

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "SEC_USERS")
    private Integer idUser;
```

> Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
>   'LAST_INSERT_ID' is not a recognized built-in function name.
>       Error Code: 195
>       Call: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
>       Query: ValueReadQuery(name="SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY" sql="SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the reason behind this exception, but I solved my problem using database table for identifier generation as described here [eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PrimaryKey)